# Forcing the foreground layer to scroll instead of the background

Tags: html, css

I have a pop-up layer with a contact form that shows when a user clicks on the "Contact" button. The layer is coded something like this:

```
<div id="form-overlay">
    <div class="form-layer">
        <h2>Fill This Form</h2>
        <form>
        ......Form fields, Text.....
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the associated style definitions are:

```
#form-overlay {position: fixed;top: 0;bottom: 0;left: 0;right: 0;background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);z-index:100;display:none}
    @media (max-width: 750px), (max-height: 650px) {
        #form-overlay {position: absolute}
    }
.form-layer {position:relative;background-color:#eeeeee;width:90%;max-width:750px;z-index: 102;margin:20px auto;color:#333;padding:20px;font-weight:300}
```

The problem is that in some languages (German, Dutch especially) the text is much longer, taking up multiple lines, and pushes the Submit button below the fold, especially on smaller laptops.

When users try to scroll, the background scrolls, but the fixed position doesn't allow the form to scroll. This isn't ideal, of course, as users can't submit the form then.

If I don't make the form fixed, when users scroll down, the dark grey overlay ends at the screen height and then that looks odd.

Question: How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Please, provide jsfiddle.

Comment: Not a perfect replica, but it gives an idea of the issue on hand: https://jsfiddle.net/uf7n3q5y/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try to add 'overflow:auto' on #form-overlay block. It could help )

Comment: Thanks - that does seem to solve the issue. However, it also seems to include a 2nd scroll bar (though that merges with the primary scrollbar if I magnify it beyond 150%). Is there any way to prevent the appearance of the 2nd scroll bar at all?

Answer (score 0):

Hide 'overflow: hidden;' on background and enable 'overflow: auto;' on foreground.